# on specific click of radio button enable text-box/dropdown list in mvc using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have three radio buttons and one dropdown list.
On click third radio button dropdown list should appear else it should be disabled. how to check condtion on third radio button based on its 'id' property using jquery in mvc. Help me I am very new jquery..

```js
    $("document").ready(function () {

        //This is to hide and disable dropdown on page load intially
        $("#ddSectionlsts").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#ddSectionlsts").hide();
 
        $('input:radio').click(function () {

            //This is to hide and disable dropdown on any click of radio button
            $("#ddSectionlsts").hide();
            $("#ddSectionlsts").prop("disabled", true);

            if ($(this).val=="radiospecific") {  //what is suitable condtion to check 
                //on success of condition dropdown is enabled for selection
                $("#ddSectionlsts").show();
                $("#ddSectionlsts").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Name1, new { @id = "radiocomman", @name="type", @class="test_Css" }) Cheque
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Name2, new { @id = "radiospecific", @name = "type", @class = "test_css" })Cas
</div>

@*drop down list*@
@{var listItems = new List<ListItem>
    {
          new ListItem { Text = "Exemplo1", Value="Exemplo1" },
          new ListItem { Text = "Exemplo2", Value="Exemplo2" },
          new ListItem { Text = "Exemplo3", Value="Exemplo3" }
    };
}
  
@Html.DropDownList("Exemplo", new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text"),new{ @id = "ddSectionlsts", @disabled = "disabled"})
 </body>
```

Comment: You have un-grouped radio buttons. You can select both of them! And whats the point of binding to a model property when you don't give them a value attribute?

Comment: `$('input:radio')` better written as `$('input[type=radio')` which allows modern browsers an opportunity to optimize the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('input[name=type]').click(function(){        
        if ($(this).attr('id")=="radiospecific") {
            $("#ddSectionlsts").show();
            $("#ddSectionlsts").prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $("#ddSectionlsts").hide();
            $("#ddSectionlsts").prop("disabled", true);

        }
});
```

Comment: OP does not have any radio buttons with `name="type"` One is `name="Name1"` and the other is `name="Name2"` - setting `new { @name = "type"` } does not change the `name` attribute (fortunately)

Comment: This is working good but its allowing multiple radio button selection(click)

Answer (score 0):

> Your radio buton

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Name1, "Cheque", new { @id = "radiocomman", @name="type", @class="test_Css" }) Cheque
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Name2, "Cas", new { @id =   "radiospecific", @name = "type", @class = "test_css" })Cas

Your Js

    $('input:radio').click(function(){       
    var radioVal = $('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val();
    if (radioVal == 'Cheque') {
        $("#ddSectionlsts").prop("disabled", false).show();
    }
    else if (radioVal == 'Cas'){
        $("#ddSectionlsts").prop("disabled", false).hide();
    }});

In your Model

public string type { get; set; }
```

Comment: 'Cheque' and 'Cas' are some random labels 
and the above code is working fine with HTML and in mvc it is not responding to click of radio buttons

Comment: Cheque and cas are values for label Cheque and cas  respectivelly

Comment: Have you added the type property in model class. Have same radio button what I posted in ans, it includes the value for radio button

Comment: Yes i have defined type in model. I am getting 'radioVal' has undefined in debugger

Comment: Is your click event triggers, try with change event, Can you add your rendered html code for radio button(Use F12)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="rb" class="mrb" id="rButton1" value="rb1">Radio Button 1 <br>
<input type="radio" name="rb" class="mrb" id="rButton2" value="rb2">Radio Button 2 <br>
<input type="radio" name="rb" class="mrb" id="rButton3" value="rb3">Radio Button 3
```

Now add a click event by class name and inside of it put you condition whether the clicked button id match with the third button or not. If yes then put your desire action inside of the loop.

```
$('.mrb').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'rButton3') {
        // put your desire action
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For two radio buttons I found this and its working correctly

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ddSectionlsts").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#ddSectionlsts").hide();
        $('input:radio').click(function () {
            $("#ddSectionlsts").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#ddSectionlsts").hide();
            if ($(this).attr('id') == 'radiospecific') {
                $("#ddSectionlsts").show();
                $("#ddSectionlsts").prop("disabled", false);
                $('#radiocomman').prop('checked', false);
            }
            else
                $('#radiospecific').prop('checked', false);
        });

    });
```

```html
<div>
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Name1, "Cheque", new { @id = "radiocomman", @name = "type", @class = "test_Css" }) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Name2, "Cas", new { @id = "radiospecific", @name = "type", @class = "test_css" })

    
</div>

@*drop down list*@
@{var listItems = new List<ListItem>
    {
          new ListItem { Text = "Example1", Value="Example1" },
          new ListItem { Text = "Example2", Value="Example2" },
          new ListItem { Text = "Example3", Value="Example3" }
    };
}
@Html.DropDownList("Example", new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text"),new{ @id = "ddSectionlsts", @disabled = "disabled"})
```